# In google colab I have faced this issue please can anyone tell me how it can be solved

Tags: python, python-3.x

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.

To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:

```
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I tried to solve this but unfortunately i couldn't